# in <picture> it is just taking the first <source> and ignoring the rest

Tags: html, css

it just changes from the img tag and the first source tag and ignoring the rest.

```
        <picture>
            <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/800x700">
            <source media="(min-width: 900px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/900x800">
            <source media="(min-width: 1000px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1000x900">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400" alt="">
        </picture>
```

Comment: Could you further describe the problem? What is the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

The `<source>` tag is used to specify multiple media resources for media elements, such as `<video>`, `<audio>`, and `<picture>`.

The `<source>` tag allows you to specify alternative video/audio/image files which the browser may choose from, based on its media type, codec support or media query.

So, it this behavior is normal, only the first element will be displayed. If you want more than one, you should use another tag.